# How does a fourier transform project onto sinusoids?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

It looks like a Discrete Fourier Transform can take N sampled data points, and find weights for sinusoids of N different frequencies, which will *exactly* recreate the original N sampled data points: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform

Having done a lot of reading, I have a good understanding of what it is doing, and why it should *approximately* recreate the input points. But I don't see why it should be *exact*? Most articles only explain why you expect it to be similar-ish.

It measures the "similarity" of the signal to waves of different frequencies, by summing/integrating the *product* of the wave and the original signal. But why the product? Sure, when both are very positive, it gives a large positive value, or when both are negative, they multiply to a large positive value. Seems sensible.

...but why not sum/integrate something like the *difference* of the original signal, and a particular sinusoid? Seems like this would be a more accurate measure of how closely it matches that frequency?

But using the product is not only better than using the difference, it's actually *perfect*! It finds the intensities of the sinusoids needed to *exactly* recreate the input data points! Why? How?

I understand that it should be *possible* (N data points, and N frequency intensities, same N degrees of freedom).  But why is the formula involving the product the correct, exact answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else reading this, I got some great answers over on Reddit’s AskMath community: https://www.reddit.com/r/askmath/comments/dvkd18/

Also, while not exactly answering my question, this was also helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2113682/725067