# Cross product-like quantity for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, vectors

I have the quantity:
\begin{equation}
I=  \sum_{i>j=1}^n \left( a_i b_j -a_j b_i \right)^2,
\end{equation}
where $a_i, b_i$ are real numbers.

In the case of $n=3$, I can interpret this as the magnitude of the vector resulting from the cross product of the two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$: $A=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $B=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$, which geometrically, is related to the area of the parallelogram that these two vectors span.

My question is the following: when $n>3$, is there some geometric interpretation of what does this quantity define (if any) in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and more specifically for the vectors defined by $A=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $B=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ in analogy with the $n=3$ case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product

Comment: I don't think that the cross product for $n=7$ reduces to the quantity $I$ that I defined above. More importantly, even if it does, I am interested in the general case for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: There's always the wedge product (which is arguably more appropriate in most places where one sees the cross product anyways). I can't find any source on them that's not terribly dense though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Lagrange.27s_identity:

$$
\sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} \left(a_ib_j-a_jb_i \right)^2 = \left\| \mathbf a \right\| ^2 \left\| \mathbf b \right\| ^2 - (\mathbf {a \cdot b } )^2
$$

In the $n = 3$ case this matches $\|a \times b\|^2$ as noted on the same page, and so does for $n = 7$ per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity#Seven_dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{i < j} \left(a_ib_j-a_jb_i \right)^2 = \|\mathbf a\wedge \mathbf b\|^2$$

which is just the square of the area of the parallelogram with sides $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$.  That's pretty geometric, I think. ;)

---

If $\{\mathbf e_1, \cdots, \mathbf e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$, then it is easily shown from the [properties of the wedge product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395970/what-is-the-logic-rationale-behind-the-vector-cross-product/1471129#1471129) that $\mathbf a\wedge \mathbf b \in \Lambda V$ is given by $$\mathbf a\wedge \mathbf b = \sum_{i \lt j} (a_ib_j-a_jb_i)\mathbf e_i \wedge \mathbf e_j$$

Then we *define* the norm of this by $$\|\mathbf a \wedge \mathbf b\|^2 = \sum_{i < j} \left(a_ib_j-a_jb_i \right)^2$$