# Difference between Scalar Multiplication and Orthogonal Projection

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook is in Swedish so I am sorry if the wording is a bit weird or if things have got another name in english. Anyway, I am confused regarding Scalar Multiplication and Orthogonal projection, especially how scalar multiplication is used to derive the formula for orthogonal projection.

Scalar multiplication is defined as: $$|u| \cdot |v| \cdot \cos [u,v]$$
Orthogonal projection is defined as $$u' = \frac{u\cdot v}{|v|^2} \cdot v$$

From what I understand the difference between these is that scalar multiplication produces a magnitude, while orthogonal projection produces a vector.

I am trying to prove the formula for orthogonal projection myself and I have come up with the follwing:

Define $$ e = \frac{1}{|v|} \cdot v$$
i.e a normalized vector in the direction of v. 
Now, the magnitude times the direction would produce the full vector correct? So:

$$ u' = |u|\cdot|v|\cdot\cos [u,v] \cdot e = \frac{|u|\cdot|v|\cdot\cos [u,v] \cdot v}{|v|}$$

Which gives $$\frac{u\cdot v\cdot v}{|v|}$$

Which is **not** the formula for orthogonal projection. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should distinguish between the different types of multiplication you have going on.  For instance in the equation $u' = \dfrac{u*v}{|v|^2} * v$, the first $*$ should be the dot product/ scalar product, whereas the second $*$ should denote scaling the vector $v$ by the scalar quantity in front of it.  So maybe a better way to write it would be $$u' = \frac{u \cdot v}{\|v\|^2} v$$

Comment: @Bye_World Yeah sorry I am quite new to linear-algebra so I am not familiar with the notation.

Comment: [Here](http://mathinsight.org/dot_product) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395970/what-is-the-logic-rationale-behind-the-vector-cross-product/1471129#1471129) are two resources that might help you see where the orthogonal projection formula come from.

Comment: Your problem is in thinking that the length of $u'$ should be $\|u\|\|v\|\cos(\theta)$.  It should actually just be $\|u\|\cos(\theta)$ (try to draw a picture to confirm this).  So then you end up with $u'= \|u\|\cos(\theta)e = \frac{\|u\|\cos(\theta)}{\|v\|}v$.  Then if you multiply this by $1=\frac{\|v\|}{\|v\|}$ you get the orthogonal projection formula.