# How to project $x_2$ onto $u_1$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm following a solution from [here](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~sunik/06math601/s08.pdf) (the first problem), I don't understand how to "*project $x_2$ onto $u_1$"*

> 1) how does:$\begin{bmatrix}0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$ turn into $\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\2\end{bmatrix}$?
>
> 2) how does: $x_1 - proj = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\-2\end{bmatrix}$ ?? Shouldn't it be $\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the answer you'd benefit from here is a description of how the Gram-Schmidt process works.

---

### Orthogonal Projection

To understand that we need to understand orthogonal projection.  First we consider the orthogonal projection of a vector $\vec v$ onto the one-dimensional subspace $\operatorname{span}(\vec u)$.  It is defined to be the *unique* component -- denoted $\vec v_\|$ or $\operatorname{proj}_{\vec u}(\vec v)$ -- of $\vec v$ parallel to $\vec u$ such that $$\vec v = \vec v_\| + \vec v_\bot,\quad \vec v_\bot \cdot \vec u = 0$$

[image][image]

Before I give the formula, I'll give a geometric definition of the dot product that should make it much easier to understand where the formula comes from: the dot product $\vec v \cdot \vec u$ is the *signed* length of the projection of $\vec v$ onto $\operatorname{span}(\vec u)$ times the length of $\vec u$ where the sign is determined by the equation $\operatorname{proj}_{\vec u}(\vec v) = \lambda \vec u$ -- if $\lambda >0$, then the sign is $+$, otherwise it is $-$.  For slightly more on this you can see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395970/what-is-the-logic-rationale-behind-the-vector-cross-product/1471129#1471129).

Then it should be easy to convince yourself that $$\operatorname{proj}_{\vec u}(\vec v) = \frac{\vec v\cdot \vec u}{\|\vec u\|^2}\vec u$$

*(Note: don't take this as the definition of* $\operatorname{proj}_{\vec u}(\vec v)$ *or else we just get a circular set of definitions.  The definition is in the first paragraph of this section* -- *this is just a formula for how to* ***calculate*** $\operatorname{proj}_{\vec u}(\vec v)$*)*

But we don't only want to project a vector onto a one-dimensional subspace -- often we want to project a vector onto an arbitrary-dimensional subspace $U$.

[image]

Once we have the one-dimensional orthogonal projection down, it's not too hard to extend it.  Say we have an **orthonormal** basis $\{\vec u_1, \dots, \vec u_k\}$ for the subspace $U$.  Then the orthogonal projection of $\vec v$ onto $U$ will simply be the sum of the projections onto each $\operatorname{proj}_{\vec u_i}(\vec v)$:

$$\operatorname{proj}_{U}(\vec v) = \sum_{i=1}^k \operatorname{proj}_{\vec u_i}(\vec v) = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\vec v\cdot \vec u_i}{\|\vec u_i\|^2}\vec u_i$$

Now ask yourself: why is this formula correct?  Does the basis $\{\vec u_i\}$ really need to be orthonormal? (Hint for the second one: the answer is not quite, we can relax that restriction a little.  Why?)

Now we have all the tools we need to describe the Gram-Schmidt process.

---

### The Gram-Schmidt Process

Let's say we have a basis $\{\vec b_1, \dots, \vec b_k\}$ of some $k$-dimensional subspace.  That's great, but sometimes what we really want is an *orthonormal* basis.  So that begs the question "is there some way of turning an arbitrary basis $\{\vec b_i\}$ into an orthonormal basis {\hat e_i}$?"  The answer is yes.  Here's the procedure:

First we're going to create an intermediate basis $\{\vec f_i\}$ which is orthogonal, but not necessarily orthonormal.  We do so via a recurrence relation:

$$\begin{align}\vec f_1 &:= \vec b_1 \\ \vec f_i &:= \vec b_i - \operatorname{proj}_{U_{i-1}}(\vec b_i),\quad \text{for }1\lt i\le k\end{align}$$

where $U_{i-1} = \operatorname{span}(f_1, \dots, f_{i-1})$.

So what's happening here?  Well first we just take the vector $\vec b_1$ and set $\vec f_1$ equal to it.  Then for $\vec f_2$ we take $\vec b_2$ and *subtract its projection* onto $\vec f_1$.  So what's left is just the component of $\vec b_2$ *which is orthogonal* to $\vec f_1$.  Then for $\vec f_3$ we take $\vec b_3$ and subtract off its projection onto $\vec f_1$ and $\vec f_2$ to get just the part orthogonal to both.  We continue in this way until we have an **orthogonal** basis $\{\vec f_i\}$.

But we didn't just want an orthogonal set, we wanted an orthonormal set.  But now the normalization part is easy.  We just set $\hat e_i := \frac{\vec f_i}{\|\vec f_i\|}$ for all $i$.

Then we're done.  We've created an orthonormal basis $\{\hat e_i\}$ from an arbitrary basis $\{\vec b_i\}$ which necessarily describes the *same subspace*.  Success!