# Find $\vec v \cdot\vec w$

Tags: vectors

Suppose $\Vert\space \vec v\space\Vert$ = 2, $\Vert \space proj_\vec v \space\vec w\space\Vert$ = 5, and the angle between $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ is obtuse. Find $\vec v \cdot\vec w$.

Using what was given, I can deduce that the solution is most likely a negative quantity since the angle between $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ is obtuse.

Also, $proj_\vec v \space\vec w$ = $\vec v \space \cdot \space\vec w\over \Vert v \Vert^2$$\vec v$

Since $\Vert \space \vec v \space \Vert$ = 2, this will result in $proj_\vec v \space\vec w$ = $\vec v \space \cdot \space\vec w\over 4$$\vec v$. At this point, I am unsure what the next step should be to get to the final solution.

Just so you know, this is not a homework problem. I am studying for an exam and would greatly appreciate some clarification on this practice problem.

Comment: Hint: $|\vec v \cdot \vec w| = 2 \cdot 5$. Then the sign must be...

Comment: One way to geometrically [define the dot product](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395970/what-is-the-logic-rationale-behind-the-vector-cross-product/1471129#1471129) is $v \cdot w = \begin{cases}\|\operatorname{proj}_vw\|\|v\|, & \angle \text{ acute} \\ -\|\operatorname{proj}_vw\|\|v\|, & \angle \text{ obtuse}\end{cases}$

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for the hint. I understand that a negative value for the dot product of two vectors means the angle between them must be obtuse.

Comment: @Bye_World Are you implying that the answer is simply $\vec v \space \cdot \space \vec w$ = $\Vert \space \vec v \space \Vert$ $\cdot$ $\Vert proj_\vec v \space \vec w \Vert$?

Comment: @sYnChris The negative of that, yes.

Comment: @Bye_World Ah I see. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\| \operatorname{proj}_v u \| = \left| \frac{u \cdot v}{\| v\|} \right|$$